# Is total differentiability analogous to differentiability

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is called totally differentiable at a point $a\in \mathbb{R^n}$ if $\exists$ a linear transformation $T_a$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+hv)-f(a) - T_a(h,v)}{h}}\| = 0
\end{equation}

A functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable if following limit exists
\begin{equation}
{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}
\end{equation}

Both definitions seem very similar to me.
So my question is that is total differentiability a generalised concept of differentiability

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Personally, I cannot give an interpretation as of content of the first definition, due to several mismatches between functions and their arguments.

Comment: Secondly, to me the second definition is the definition of being differentiable at $a$ with derivative equal to $0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Sorry I wanted to write something else and changed it at last second. I forgot to remove 0 in second definition